# Plugging in/Unplugging dynamic mics with the channel on

Tags: microphone

Is it true that plugging in/unplugging dynamic mics when the channel is turned on can lead to damage to the mic? If it is true, shouldn't it be true of damage to any equipment connected using XLR connectors?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, some old capacitor microphones could be damaged by phantom power, so you were always expected to wait 30 seconds after turning off phantom power before unplugging the microphone, and never to plug in microphones while phantom power was on!

Not so sure it is an issue these days - of more concern is that when you unplug, you may get a very loud signal at the amps or desk - which could potentially damage them!

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I was asking about dynamic microphones, which don't use phantom power. I had read somewhere that if the mixer channel is on, plugging/unplugging a *dynamic* mic could damage the mic. But this doesn't make sense to me so I asked here.